# Equivalence of two forms of initializer lists in std::vector and others

Tags: c++

I've got a very simple question:

are(1st):

```
std::vector<int> foo{1,2,3};
```

and(2nd):

```
std::vector<int> foo({1,2,3});
```

Strictly the same? As in, do they have the exact same functionality and call the exact same functions inside std::vector?

Is there any case in which these two differ in any other similar container class or use case?

How does std::vector differentiate between initializer lists and constructor calls in the first code extract? Aren't curly brackets used for both?

Comment: You can find all the information you need [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Even if it's not spelled out in the most easily digested way.

Answer (score 0):

they are different

{} adds the values to vector

() calls the constructor all the types of constructor are in link given below

[redirected  to cplusplus](http://int%20x%5B3%5D%5B4%5D%20=%20%7B%7B0,1,2,3%7D,%20%7B4,5,6,7%7D,%20%7B8,9,10,11%7D%7D;)

Is there any case in which these two differ in any other similar container class or use case?

When you add a element to a vector using functions like push_back() etc. we use
vec_name.push_back(element); //normal paranthesis not curly brackets

when you create multi-dimension array or vector and initialize the elements from it's declaration for e.g for 2D array it is as follows
int x[3][4] = {{0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7}, {8,9,10,11}};

Main two uses of curly parenthesis in cpp are :

1. while you declare a segment of code for eg. for(parameters) { } , main(parameters){} ,function(parameters) etc.
2. for initializing values at the beginning

The use of normal paranthesis is for passing parameters or argument to a function